# Mac does not remember Windows keyboard settings when reconnecting

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a Mac (OS X) in clamshell mode with a Windows USB keyboard attached.

A known issue is that the <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd> keys are swapped on the Windows keyboard. Namely, by default, the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key is <kbd>command</kbd> and it is in the "wrong" place.

In `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys...` one can redefine this, and have the USB keyboard with the same order of `alt+command` keys.

However, my problem is how to save/keep this setting. In particular, once I disconnect-reconnect my keyboard, I have to redefine the setting. Is there a way to save this?

Comment: Closed as per OP's request - `The problem didn't happen again (regardless of this thread). I think this question has to be removed. I cannot mark an answer as excepted since I didn't have, eventually, to try the suggested solution`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a program called [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) that does what you want. From [this blog](http://theos.in/apple/download-doublecommand-to-remap-keyboard-keys/):

> DoubleCommand is software for Mac OS X (a kernel extension) that lets
>   you remap keys, in other words change the way your keyboard works.
>   Often used to make a PC keyboard more comfortable with a Mac, swapping
>   the Alt (Option) and Windows (Command or Apple) keys

I found this searching for '[mac remap keys keyboard](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=mac%20remap%20keys%20keyboard)' on Google, did you not find this?

Comment: I found it, but I was hopping I can solve the issue without a 3rd party tool. Actually, as I mentioned, I solved it within the OS X, the only issue is that the system doesn't remember my preferences with the USB keyboard... In case there will be no solution, I will try this tool - but it's a second option for me.

Comment: I see. There are probably some system files that influence this behaviour, the trouble is finding which. Perhaps using DoubleCommand you can find these files (`lsof`) and change them manually? Or uninstall the tool once you're done.